# Textbox.Text Rearranging String Contents

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am having trouble with setting value of a textbox in code on a winforms application.  I must be missing something simple.  I've reduced the error down to the following code:

```
string val = "11/02/2020 17:52";
txtPhotosVerifiedOn.Text = val;
```

When I run the program, the textbox displays the following:

```
17:52 11/02/2020
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why the textbox is rearranging the date and time.  It should be a simple string, right?  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: *strings* don't change them selves. Id search for all usages of `txtPhotosVerifiedOn` or events

Comment: Something else is modifying the value. If you open a new project, add a textbox with that name to the form, put your sample code in the form `Load` event, it will look as you expect.

Comment: You have `RightToLeft` enabled or it gets enabled at some point or you change the language and the current Culture has a RTL setup. Check `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft` (or maybe `txtPhotosVerifiedOn..RightToLeft`)

Comment: Jimi figured it out!!  Thank you!!  That was driving me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurred due to Current Culture so please change your the CurrentCulture details as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Jimi figured it out.  The `RightToLeft` property was set to `Yes` on these textboxes.  Setting them to `No` fixed the problem.  Thanks again, Jimi!